# SQL revenue analysis

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to break down the Revenue into how much is contributed by (x) product

```
   select
      pro_id,
      to_char(so_date,'YYYY') as year,
      sum(sod_qty*sod_price_unit) over(partition by to_char(so_date,'YYYY'))
    from all_sales;
```

Here is the output that I get, which will show the total sales for each particular year:

> PRO_ID|   YEAR  |  Total Sales
> S0010   |  2023   |33962.8
> S0011   |   2023  |33962.8
> S0002   |   2023  |33962.8

[image: total sales for each year]

```
SELECT
pro_id, pro_name,
to_char(so_date, 'YYYY') As year,
SUM(SOD_QTY*SOD_PRICE_UNIT) AS total_sales
FROM all_sales
GROUP BY pro_id, pro_name, so_date
Order by pro_id, pro_name;
```

The output below showed sales for each product for each year:

[image]

I not sure how to calculate it in the percentage form

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as properly formatted text, i.e. no images, no links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the year (not the underlying date) and then use an analytic function to calculate the total sales for the year and use that to calculate the percentage:

```sql
SELECT pro_id,
       pro_name,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM so_date) As year,
       SUM(SOD_QTY*SOD_PRICE_UNIT) AS total_sales,
       SUM(SOD_QTY*SOD_PRICE_UNIT)
       / SUM(SUM(SOD_QTY*SOD_PRICE_UNIT))
           OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM so_date))
       * 100 AS percentage_sales
FROM   all_sales
GROUP BY
       pro_id,
       pro_name,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM so_date)
ORDER BY
       pro_id,
       pro_name;
```